# Get all records between two weeks

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to get all records between two week numbers. This is the query I'm using right now:

```
SELECT huxwz_user_orders . * , huxwz_users.name, huxwz_users.email FROM huxwz_user_orders
LEFT OUTER JOIN huxwz_users ON ( huxwz_user_orders.userid = huxwz_users.id )
WHERE
   (STATUS=3 or STATUS=2)
    AND plannedweek > 0 
    AND plannedweek >= WEEK(DATE_ADD(now(), interval 1 WEEK))
    AND plannedweek < WEEK(DATE_ADD(now(), interval 3 WEEK))
    AND NOT plannedweek=0
```

The query works very well and returns all records between the two provided weeks. **HOWEVER** When I add like 16 to the < ending of the query. MySQL interprets the 16 weeks should be added to the current week (42), So it's 16+42 = 58. Since we dont have 58 weeks and only 52, it must be the sixth week. This is exactly how it should do.

Problem is, when I want to find all records between two values and it does like above. It's going to look like this:

Get all records that are > 42 and < 16. This makes no sense, and it will obviously not return anything.

So, my records have a year, so I do know what year it is. I was thinking something along the lines: If the week, is next year, add 52 to the value. This is unreliable though, since  not every year has 52 weeks.

How would I do this?

Any suggestions / solutions?

Comment: I would look for a way to use date fields instead of planned weeks.  A week number without an associated year is ambiguous.

Comment: SELECT YEARWEEK(NOW()+INTERVAL 16 WEEK,1); = 201406

Comment: That is not at all what I'm looking for :i

Answer (score 0):

It looks like @Strawberry's comment is on the right track.

I corrected Strawberry's omission of the DATE_ADD() function, plus we need to adapt the value of planned week to match the results of the YEARWEEK() function.

e.g.:

```
SELECT huxwz_user_orders . * , huxwz_users.name, huxwz_users.email FROM huxwz_user_orders
LEFT OUTER JOIN huxwz_users ON ( huxwz_user_orders.userid = huxwz_users.id )
WHERE
   (STATUS=3 or STATUS=2)
    AND plannedweek > 0 
    AND (YEAR( NOW() ) * 100) + plannedweek >= YEARWEEK( WEEK(DATE_ADD(now(), interval 1 WEEK)), 1)
    AND (YEAR( NOW() ) * 100) + plannedweek < YEARWEEK( WEEK(DATE_ADD(now(), interval 3 WEEK)), 1) 
    AND NOT plannedweek=0
```

If this doesn't work then your question may need some further clarification.